# How to equal two different ids from another table?

Tags: php, mysql

```
select student.student_fname,
student.student_mname,
student.student_lname, logs.time, logs.transaction,logs.entity_type,prof.professor_fname,prof.professor_mname,prof.professor_lname 
from student_tbl as student,
logs_tbl as logs,
professor_tbl as prof 
where student.student_id=logs.entity_id 
and prof.professor_id=logs.entity_id
and logs.date ='$date_today' 
and logs.course_id='$course' 
and logs.sections_id='$sections'
and logs.rooms_id='$room'  
group by logs.date, 
logs.term, 
logs.course_id, 
logs.entity_id  
order by logs.logs_id asc
```

In student_tbl and professor_tbl I have student_id and professor_id that is equal to the entity_id of logs_tbl. How do i compare those two id from different tables to entity_id in logs_tbl? it is the only line that is giving me error. or maybe you have a suggestion? aside from sql injection stuff

**UPDATE**

i have **student_tbl** the columns there are: student_id, student_fname, student_mname, student_lname. i also have professor_tbl and the columns there are: **professor_id**, professor_fname, professor_mname, professor_lname, and my third table which has all the basis is the **logs_tbl** the columns there are: entity_id(this is where student_id and professor_id will equate), course_id,rooms_id,sections_id,time,date,transaction,entity_type. 
This is what i want to display:

- student_fname/professor_fname (depending on the entity_id)
- student_mname/professor_mname (depending on the entity_id)
- student_lname/professor_lname (depending on the entity_id)
- time
- transaction
- entity_type

Sample data display:

- Kris | Consta | Roca | 11:30 | in | student
- Bob | Jones | Marley | 11:32 | in | student
- Ronald | James | Leon | 11:35 | in | professor

  - Kris | Consta | Roca | 1:00 | out | student
- Bob | Jones | Marley | 1:05 | out | student
- Ronald | James | Leon | 1:06 | out | professor

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: You have to read about JOINS and use them:- [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  JOIN Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: my query is working for joining tables but this time since i am equating two id to one id it is not working

Comment: in join statement itself you can add conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  select student.student_fname,  student.student_mname, student.student_lname, logs.time, logs.transaction,logs.entity_type
          from student_tbl as student inner join logs_tbl as logs on student.student_id=logs.entity_id  
     where   logs.date ='$date_today' 
                and logs.course_id='$course' 
                and logs.sections_id='$sections'
                and logs.rooms_id='$room'  
                group by logs.date,  logs.term, 
                logs.course_id, 
                logs.entity_id   


    UNION  

      select prof.professor_fname,prof.professor_mname,prof.professor_lname , logs.time, logs.transaction,logs.entity_type
          from   professor_tbl as prof inner join logs_tbl as logs   on prof.professor_id=logs.entity_id
             where   logs.date ='$date_today' 
                and logs.course_id='$course' 
                and logs.sections_id='$sections'
                and logs.rooms_id='$room'  
                group by logs.date,  logs.term, 
                logs.course_id, 
                logs.entity_id
```

Comment: Actually we don't know the table data , So is there any data related issue then you can send us that. Or else you should update your question @ulyk

Comment: i updated my question, im very sorry for my poor understanding in joining tables

Comment: it has an error at the word all and when i deleted all it has an error on this line:
"on prof.professor_id=logs.entity_id", unrecognized keyword near on and unrecognized token near prof

Comment: THE "ALL" has unrecognized statement types

Comment: Sorry I forget to place `inner join logs_tbl as logs on ` Check now please

Comment: Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY. that's what it says and even i delete the double on. i will put a check on you since you are very helpful but can u help me on that error?

Comment: however it still says  
Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: OMG IT WORKS. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
select student.student_fname,student.student_mname,student.student_lname, logs.time, logs.transaction,logs.entity_type,prof.professor_fname,prof.professor_mname,prof.professor_lname 
from student_tbl as student
join logs_tbl as logs on student.student_id=logs.entity_id and logs.date ='$date_today' and logs.course_id='$course' and logs.sections_id='$sections' and logs.rooms_id='$room'
join professor_tbl as prof on prof.professor_id=logs.entity_id
group by logs.date, logs.term, logs.course_id, logs.entity_id 
order by logs.logs_id asc
```

You can do it using `join`.

Comment: Yes please do then I can answer in a better way

Comment: i updated my question, im very sorry for my poor understanding in joining tables